# Is there any layout xml tag to specify the position of view in "dp"?

Tags: android, android-layout

We can get the relative position of a View, in pixels, using `getLeft()`, `getTop()` etc.
Is there any tag to do the reverse in a layout xml?
Something like `android:layout_left="30dp"` or something?

Answer (score 2):

You are certainly welcome to use padding (e.g., `android:paddingLeft`) and margins (e.g., `android:layout_marginLeft`) to influence the position. However, the position is controlled primarily by the layout rules for the particular container that you are using (`LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout`, etc.).